# Spring MVC Tiles Redirect Issue

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and Tiles.
When I try to use spring prefix "redirect:" for the redirection I get a servlet exception
- "Could not resolve view...".

#### Controller

```
RequestMapping("/SUPPORT.lz")
public String generateSupportView(HttpServletRequest request)
{

    String url="http://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+"/APP";

    AuthenticatedUser user = getUser();
    /*
     * Check if a user has the role for the page he is trying to access. If
     * not redirect him to default page (home page).
     */
    if (user.getRoles() != null && !user.getRoles().contains(new Role(0, Role.RoleType.SUPPORT)))
    {
        return "redirect:"+url;
    }
    return "support.tiles";
}
```

#### dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
  <bean id="tilesViewResolver" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
        p:order="1"
        p:viewNames="*.tiles"
        p:viewClass="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>

  <bean id="nontilesViewResolver" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver"
        p:order="2"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/app-nontiles-views.xml"/>

  <bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer" 
        p:definitions="/WEB-INF/app-tiles.xml"/>

  <bean id="messageSource" 
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        p:basename="i18n"/>
```

#### Solution-

I added internal view resolver in disaptacher servlet.xml and issue got resolved.

```
 <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:order="3">
 </bean>
```

Comment: Can u put a system.out statement on the "url" variable and see if the variable is having a value that ends in .tiles??

Comment: `XmlViewResolver` has no support for the `redirect:` prefix. You should let a `UrlBasedViewResolver` handle the view.